# Merge adjacent events from an array of dates

Tags: php, algorithm, date, sorting, php-7

I am racking my brain on the math for this one, experimenting with `strtotime`, adding days, nesting `foreach`, but coming up blank. Hope someone here could kindly lead me to the right direction.

My use case is adding events to a calendar (`FullCalendar`) where I can specify a 'start' and 'end' date for an event. I have events that run over multiple days, sometimes as a solid block, sometimes the same event is broken into smaller blocks, but I would like all adjacent days of the same variation to be merged into one event using a 'start' and 'end date. My query returns just a list of days though.

The end date should always have +1 day at the end as it counts exclusively (ex. an event that runs through both the 12th and 13th should have an end date of 14th).

2020-10-01,2020-10-02,2020-10-03,2020-10-04 should be one block with a start of 2020-10-01 and end of 2020-10-05.

2020-10-08,2020-10-09,2020-10-11,2020-12-13 should be two blocks, one with a start of 08 and end of 10 and another with a start of 12 and end of 14.

Here's my code that doesn't work (just creates an event for each day):

```
$finalCourses = array();
$counter = 0;

// Loop through courses
while($allCourses->have_posts()) { $allCourses->the_post();

    // ..and loop over each Courses variations..
    global $post;
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable($post->ID);
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    foreach($variations as $variation) {
        // ..and then store each Course variation in a new array
        $variationID = $variation['variation_id'];
        $coursePrice = '£'.$variation['display_price'];
        $courseTitle = get_the_title().' - '.$coursePrice;

        // Get the comma separated list of dates in Y-m-d (2020-08-27) format
        $dates = explode(',', strip_tags(str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $variation['variation_description'])));
                
        foreach($dates as $date) {
            $start = $date;
            $end = $start;
            
            // Now I'm stuck
            foreach($dates as $endTest) {
                if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endTest)) === date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end . "+1 day"))) {
                    $end = $endTest;
                } else {
                    $finalCourses[$counter] = array(
                        'id'     => $variationID,
                        'title'  => (string)$courseTitle,
                        'start'  => $start,
                        'end' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end . "+1 day"))
                    );
                    $counter++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am encoding the output as JSON which currently looks like this (with one course and two variations ID 541 and 542).

```
{
id: 542,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £300",
start: "2020-09-07",
end: "2020-09-08"
},
{
id: 542,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £300",
start: "2020-09-08",
end: "2020-09-09"
},
{
id: 542,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £300",
start: "2020-09-09",
end: "2020-09-10"
},
{
id: 542,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £300",
start: "2020-09-10",
end: "2020-09-11"
},
{
id: 542,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £300",
start: "2020-09-12",
end: "2020-09-13"
},
{
id: 541,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £250",
start: "2020-08-31",
end: "2020-09-01"
},
{
id: 541,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £250",
start: "2020-09-01",
end: "2020-09-02"
},
{
id: 541,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £250",
start: "2020-09-02",
end: "2020-09-03"
},
{
id: 541,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £250",
start: "2020-09-03",
end: "2020-09-04"
},
{
id: 541,
title: "RYA Competent Crew - £250",
start: "2020-09-04",
end: "2020-09-05"
}
]
```

As you can see, each day is output as its own event but all adjacent days of the same variation ID should be joined as one.

I'd be immensely grateful for any hint or pointer.

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `$finalCourses` look like after you generate it?

Comment: Thank you Darren, I have added the JSON output of the JSON encoded `$finalCourses` array.

Comment: it looks like your `$variationID` stays the same the entire time throughout the loops yes? If so, what you're saying is that you should have 2 events (as blocks) that run from:`#1 - 2020-08-31 to 2020-09-04` & `#2 - 2020-09-07 to 2020-09-13`, correct?

Comment: From the first `foreach` yes the variation ID stays the same. The first `while` loop loops through variations but that shouldn't be a problem. On variation ID `542` the `2020-09-11` is skipped breaking that one in to two blocks like in the calendar screenshot. The first week contains 541 and the second 542. 

The gap in 542 should stay there and only the adjacent days connected in to one calendar event.

Apologies the terminology is all a bit off here I am working within the confines of a CMS output.

Comment: ahhhh so the event's shouldn't run on a weekend - hence the split on `2020-09-11`?

Comment: The events can run whenever, maybe even split over multiple weeks and maybe weekends too. This is just the demo I set-up so I can test an event/variation as a single block (541 in the first week) and an event/variation broken up into two calendar blocks (542 in the second week).

Answer (score 0):

From what you've mentioned - I think you've almost got it! The only issue I could see was that you were creating a new "event" array item each time, instead of updating the original one :)

You're better off comparing the timestamp's delivered from `strtotime()` as below.

```
foreach ($dates as $endTest) {
    // compare the new date (if more recent [higher] than previous), should update it..
    if (strtotime($endTest) > strtotime($end . "+1 day")) {
        /**
         * update the event to set the end date, instead of re-creating it.
         */
        $finalCourses[$variationID]['end'] = $endTest;
    } else {
        // create event with the "$variationID" as the id we want to use...
        $finalCourses[$variationID] = array(
            'id' => $variationID,
            'title' => (string) $courseTitle,
            'start' => $start,
            'end' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end . "+1 day"))
        );
        $counter++;
        break;
    }
}
```

*Please note; the code above is only as an example of what to do and for you to use as a general idea.*